# TextView wont hide if data is null

Tags: android, android-intent, textview

I have two activities i.e. MainActivity and NewActivity.On click of button in MainActivity,i am moving to NewActivity using Intent and passing some data using intent to NewActivity.

```
intent.putExtra("PUBLISHEDAT",newses.get(position).getTitle());
```

In NewActivity,i am checking whether the data received from Intent is null or not.If it is null i am setting the TextView visibility to GONE.But textview won't disappear and displays null even if data received from intent is null.

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("PUBLISHEDAT")==null || getIntent().getStringExtra("PUBLISHEDAT")==""){
            publishedAtTextView.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("PUBLISHEDAT").trim().equals("")
```

or

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("PUBLISHEDAT").trim().isEmpty()
```

Comment: Tried both.Not working.I also tried printing getIntent().getStringExtra("PUBLISHEDAT").trim(),it shows null.

Comment: publishedAtTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE); this seems wrong!

Comment: you are missing View.

Comment: the correct way to setVisibilty is calling View.GONE , in your case it's just Gone!!

Comment: I have imported import static android.view.View.GONE; so i don't need to write View.GONE.

Comment: Does the app crash?

Comment: No the app does not crash.I even wrote getIntent().getStringExtra("PUBLISHEDAT").trim().length()==0,but it doesn't work

Comment: Does it go into the if block or it doesn't?

Comment: It doesnt,it always goes to the else block where i have written condition if it has data

Comment: Too strange, define a string variable and check it's value before if block.

Comment: String string = getIntent().getStringExtra("PUBLISHEDAT");

Comment: It would be funny but now change your if condition to this:

Comment: if(string.equals(null) || string.equals("null") )

Comment: Did you try it?Any luck?

Comment: You are treating null as an strin it seems

Comment: getIntent().getStrinExtra("PUBLISHEDAT").trim().equals("null")

This should work

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `==` to check for empty string. `==` compares the reference, not the value. Use this:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("PUBLISHEDAT").isEmpty()
```

Comment: .I did this if(getIntent().getStringExtra("PUBLISHEDAT").isEmpty()){
            publishedAtTextView.setVisibility(GONE);
        }.Doesn't work

Comment: Even if i write  if(getIntent().getStringExtra("PUBLISHEDAT").equals(null)),it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think in putExtra part you put wrong value, maybe "null" as a string !

Check that with some hard coded values, like
""   "Null" and "Test" check your main activity, because in new activity you did it right